# Block onclick events when activity is paused

Tags: android, android-widget

I am able to get onClick event running on a paused activity. I thought it should not happen,
and I am hoping for some clues on how to fix this.

In my Activity (extends RoboFragmentActivity) I have a simple TextView entry for date.
OnClick event of this TextView is showing a DatePickerFragment:

```
public void onDateRowBoxClick(View view) {
    new DatePickerFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

I also have an AsyncTask, which in its OnPostExecute event starts another activity.
The AsyncTask shows a progress dialog (the operation takes several seconds), which hides the date view.

During the AsyncTask.doInBackground operation I am clicking the area on the progress dialog, which hides the date view. After the async task completes, the progress dialog is dismissed and another activity should be starting.

Instead, I am getting the onClick event on the date view. It throws up with IllegalStateException, because the activity is already paused and the fragments cannot deal with it (I get IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity, IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState; at onDateRowBoxClick). However I think the event should not be passed to a paused activity. My questions are: am I right and how to fix this?

For now I have this workaround, but it's rather silly:

```
boolean paused = true;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    paused = false;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    paused = true;
}

public void onDateRowBoxClick(View view) {
    if (!paused)
        new DatePickerFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

BTW, at first I thought it is relevant to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19917, but the workaround do not work for me.